# some Javascript Code is not being rendered while using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, php, html

PHP Code

```
<input type="text" placeholder="ID" name="instructor_id"><br>
<div class="errors">
    <strong id="errorSeven"></strong> 
</div>
```

```
$queryCheck1 = "SELECT instructor_id FROM instructor WHERE instructor_id = $instructorId";
$queryCheck1 = mysqli_query($conn, $queryCheck1);
$countCheck1 = mysqli_num_rows($queryCheck1);
if ($countCheck1 == 1) {
    ?>      
    <script>
        document.getElementById("errorSeven").innerHTML = "<strong style=\"color:red\">&#9733 
        </strong>Instructor Id is already asscociated with another instructor.";
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

The html element with the id="errorSeven" does exist but nothing happens even though the if statement is true

The error from the javascript must be printed in the element with the id="errorSeven" when the user enters an id that already exists in the database.

the same code is being used in many different places and it works fine but here it doesn't. even though the if statement returns true and number of rows of the `select` statement equals 1.
I printed a statement inside the `if` statement and it got printed

Comment: Please do not reask the same question. You have already asked that question today: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63755267/1839439

Answer (score -2):

Open the browser's developer tools console and look at the error message there.

A JS string *cannot* have a literal new line in it.

Answer (score -2):

Your script need to execute the JS only when the page is rendered.

Try this :

```
$queryCheck1 = "SELECT instructor_id FROM instructor WHERE instructor_id = $instructorId";
$queryCheck1 = mysqli_query($conn, $queryCheck1);
$countCheck1 = mysqli_num_rows($queryCheck1);
if ($countCheck1 == 1) {
    ?>      
    <script>
        document.getElementById("errorSeven").innerHTML = "<strong style=\"color:red\">&#9733 
        </strong>Instructor Id is already asscociated with another instructor.";
    </script>
    <?php
}
<script>
// self executing function here
(function() {
   document.getElementById("errorSeven").innerHTML = "<strong style=\"color:red\">&#9733 
        </strong>Instructor Id is already asscociated with another instructor.";
})();
</script>
```

Comment: I tried doing what you said, but it didn't work.
like i said before i used the same code in a different place for a different condition and it worked just fine --- Here is the Code






if (empty($_POST['instructor_id'])) {
    ?>
    <script>document.getElementById("errorSeven").innerHTML = "<strong style=\"color:red\">&#9733 </strong>Instructor Id is required.";
   </script>
   <?php
  }

Comment: And why not directly echo the variable in errorSeven div directly in PHP ?

Comment: how should i do that ?
i am not checking dynamically, the php code will validate this after the user clicks on the button